# Rust recursive reference to "self" in another struct

Tags: rust

I have two Rust structs that implements different methods (A and B), and when I instantiate B, I want this B to have A as a struct member.

In Go, this can be easily done by

```
type A struct {
  b *B
}

type B struct {
  a *A
}
```

I tried Box or Rc/RefCell but can't figure out.

This is basically what I need:

```
pub struct A<T: Tester> ...

pub struct B<T: Tester> {
  pub a: Box<A<T>>,
}

impl<T> A<T>
where
    T: Tester,
{
  pub fn run(&self) {
    let to_add = B {
      a: Box::new(self),
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

Comment: If yes, please accept the duplicate. Also note that "thanks" comment are considered noise and should not be posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question goes deep into the topic of *ownership*.

You always have to ask yourself: Who owns what?

In your case, inside the `run` function, `self` is a non-mutable reference. That means that the `self` object is owned by someone else, and we only *borrowed* it.

That sadly means that we cannot create a `Box` out of it, because that would require us to *own* `self`. (Because `Box::new()` *takes* ownership of the object it is given)

So all we *can* do is pass on the borrowed `self` object to the `B` object.

Now there is a problem, sadly, which depends on your usecase. Every borrowed object is associated with a *lifetime*, to make sure the borrow gets returned before the original object gets destroyed. And if you create a `B` object that holds a reference to `A`, the `B` object inherits that lifetime. It's certainly possible to do so, but manual lifetime management is an advanced topic in Rust because it can be frustrating to deal with.

I'd advise you to read a tutorial on how to manage lifetimes in Rust.

Just to demonstrate how this could look like:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub trait Tester {}

pub struct A<T: Tester> {
    _x: PhantomData<T>,
}

pub struct B<'a, T: Tester> {
    pub a: &'a A<T>,
}

impl<T> A<T>
where
    T: Tester,
{
    pub fn run(&self) {
        let to_add = B { a: self };
    }
}
```

Ignore the `PhantomData`, that's just a dummy to make a struct compile that has an unused generic.

The `to_add` object now has the lifetime of the `&self`, so if you try to store it somewhere externally or pass it into a thread or something similar, it will tell you that this creates a problem with its lifetime. But of course that all depends on your usecase.

---

```
type A struct {
  b *B
}

type B struct {
  a *A
}
```

This construct, in Rust, is [almost impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct). It's called a self-referencial data structure and cannot be managed by Rusts borrow checker. In its simpler form, you can use `Arc`/`Rc` to each other, which will create a memory leak (which is somewhat solveable with `Weak`, but again, many thoughts have to be put into who owns it then). In its more complicated form, you need to use raw pointers, `Pin` and `unsafe`.